# Why is the JavaScript console saying my variable is undefined, even when I defined it two lines before?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm using WebSockets to connect to a remote host, and whenever I populate `realData` and pass it to `grapher()`, the JavaScript console keeps telling me `realData`is undefined. I tried checking the type of the data in the array, but it seems to be fine. I've called `grapher()` before using an array with random data, and the call went through without any problems. With the data from the WebSocket, however, the call will always give me "error: realData is not defined". I'm not sure why this is happening. Here is the code I used:

current.html:

```
var command = "Hi Scott"

getData();

function getData()
 { 
    console.log("getData is called");

    if("WebSocket" in window)
    {
            var dataCollector = new WebSocket("ws://console.sb2.orbit-lab.org:6100",'binary');
            dataCollector.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
            console.log(dataCollector.readyState);        

            dataCollector.onopen = function()
            {
                    //alert("The WebSocket is now open!");                  

                    console.log("Ready state in onopen is: " + dataCollector.readyState);


                    dataCollector.send(command);
                    console.log(command + " sent"); 
            }

            dataCollector.onmessage = function(evt)
            {


                            console.log("onmessage is being called");
                            var realData = new Uint8Array(evt.data);
                            console.log(realData);
                            grapher(realData); //everything up to this point works perfectly.
            }

            dataCollector.onclose = function()
            {
                    alert("Connection to Server has been closed");
            }


            return (dataCollector);
    }
    else
    {
            alert("Your browser does not support WebSockets!");
    }
```

}

graphing.js:

```
function grapher(realData)
{
            console.log("grapher is called");
            setInterval('myGraph(realData);',1000); //This is where the error is. I always get "realData is not defined".

}

function myGraph(realData)
{
            /*
           for(var i = 0; i < SAarray.length; i++) // Loop which will load the channel data from the SA objects into the data array for graphing.
            {
                    var data[i] = SAarray[i];
            }
            */
            console.log("myGraph is called");

            var bar = new RGraph.Bar('channelStatus', realData);
            bar.Set('labels', ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']);
            bar.Set('gutter.left', 50);
            bar.Set('gutter.bottom', 40);
            bar.Set('ymax',100);
            bar.Set('ymin',0);
            bar.Set('scale.decimals',1);
            bar.Set('title','Channel Status');
            bar.Set('title.yaxis','Status (1 is on, 0 is off)');
            bar.Set('title.xaxis','Channel Number');
            bar.Set('title.xaxis.pos',.1);
            bar.Set('background.color','white');
            bar.Set('colors', ['Gradient(#a33:red)']);
            bar.Set('colors', ['red']);

            bar.Set('key',['Occupied','Unoccupied']);

            bar.getShapeByX(2).Set('colors',barColor(data[0]));


            bar.Draw();


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because strings (as code) passed to `setInterval` execute in the global scope, therefore the `realData` parameter isn't available. There's rarely a good reason to pass a string to `setInterval`. Instead, use:

```
setInterval(function () {
    myGraph(realData);
}, 1000);
```

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval

Comment: or with modernity, setInterval( myGraph.bind(realData), 1000 );

Comment: @dandavis No, totally different. Your solution sets the `this` value in `myGraph`, while they need to pass `realData` as the first **parameter**

Comment: oops, touche, should be , setInterval( myGraph.bind(this, realData), 1000 ); thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Perfect! I'm pretty new to JavaScript, so when the tutorial I used told me to pass a string to setInterval, I was a little confused. But this cleared everything up, and my problem was solved. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try it without it needing to evaluate a string:

```
setInterval(function() {
    myGraph(realData);
},1000);
```

Any time you are using `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, you should opt for passing an actual function instead of a string.

Comment: how original... oh wait, i see now that you omitted a whitespace when you pasted the other guys answer...

Comment: @dandavis: 5 seconds apart...there are a million people using SO, you don't think you might get the same answer once in a while?